# Tiles aren't deleting on click as supposed to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So,I have some tiles in the same tilemap,I want to delete a tile on click,All seems fine but it still doesn't work,here is the code:

```
    private Tilemap tilemap;
    void Start()
    {
        tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        Collider2D hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos));


        int posx = (int) pos.x;
        int posy = (int) pos.y ;
        int posz = (int) pos.z ;
        //Getting the position of the tile(where the mouse is)
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //on click
        {

            if (hitCollider != null && hitCollider.CompareTag("Ground"))
            {
                tilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(posx, posy, posz), null);//delete the tile
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "All seems fine " -> I recommned to add some debug log to your console and check if you're entering in the "if" blocks, and also the values of the variables at each step, to pinpoint more precisely on where your issue is.

Comment: I also tried to work with Unity's tilemap some times ago, and it's a PAIN to work with. Everything is overcomplicated, you have to write dozens of lines of code to do extremely simple things, it's a nightmare. Good luck with that lol

Comment: Thank you for your advise ,the problem is in the last line

Comment: Try replacing the tile with a blank tile not null

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply do

```
Collider2D hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos));

int posx = (int) pos.x;
int posy = (int) pos.y ;
int posz = (int) pos.z ;
```

This is simply casting a **world position** to `(int)` so removing the decimals.

---

What [`SetTile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html) expects as parameter are rather **indices** of according tiles within the given [`Grid`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html) cells.

> Unity automatically creates a Grid GameObject and sets it as the parent of a child Tilemap GameObject.

Through that `Grid` ([`Tilemap.layoutGrid`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap-layoutGrid.html)) component you can get the indices using [`Grid.WorldToCell`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html) e.g. like maybe

```
tilemap.SetTile(tilemap.gridLayout.WorldToCell(hitCollider.transform.position), null));
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*